# setting a variable intervalspeed

Tags: javascript, adobe-edge

```
var dropSpeed = 3750;
var spawnSpeed = 2000;
var i = 0;

function makeSymbol(sym)
{
    setInterval(function(){
        if(dropSpeed > 1500){dropSpeed = dropSpeed - 350;}if(spawnSpeed > 50){spawnSpeed  =     spawnSpeed - 231;}
        var aSymbol = sym.createChildSymbol("aSymbol" ,"stage");
        i = i + 1;
        symbols[i] = aSymbol.getSymbolElement();
        symbols[i].animate({top: "950px"},dropSpeed);      //uses the changed dropspeed
    },spawnSpeed);         //does not use the change spawnSpeed but keeps using the 2000
}
```

The spawnSpeed doesn't change but the dropSpeed does. how can i let the spawnspeed change? I hope it's not a stupid question but i'm stuck here for ages. you guys are my only hope. :)

Comment: and if you take this outside setTimeout() and put it before it  
if(spawnSpeed > 50){spawnSpeed  =     spawnSpeed - 231;}

Comment: just saw you use setInterval(); disregard the previous comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to change the time interval dynamically. `setInterval` is suitable for static time intervals. Instead `setTimeout` function can be used for this.

Try something like this.

```
var dropSpeed = 3750;
var spawnSpeed = 2000;
var i = 0;

function makeSymbol(sym)
{
    setTimeout(function(){
        if(dropSpeed > 1500){dropSpeed = dropSpeed - 350;}if(spawnSpeed > 50){spawnSpeed  =     spawnSpeed - 231;}
        var aSymbol = sym.createChildSymbol("aSymbol" ,"stage");
        i = i + 1;
        symbols[i] = aSymbol.getSymbolElement();
        symbols[i].animate({top: "950px"},dropSpeed);      //uses the changed dropspeed
        makeSymbol(sym);
    },spawnSpeed);         //does not use the change spawnSpeed but keeps using the 2000
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use either setTimeout or clear the interval and try to run it again. setInterval registers an interval with a specific id and timespan. That's the one, the first with the 2 seconds time span. I would prefer to use setTimeout to get over the issue. Here is a plunk, you can see the code and the results.
[Plunk here](http://plnkr.co/edit/chDQT7?p=preview)

```
function makeSymbol(sym)
{
    var test = function  (){
        if(dropSpeed > 1500){dropSpeed = dropSpeed - 350;}
        if(spawnSpeed > 50){spawnSpeed  =     spawnSpeed - 231;}
        if(spawnSpeed <= 4) spawnSpeed = 2000;

        $("#speed").text((new Date()));
        setTimeout(test, spawnSpeed);
    }
    setTimeout(test,spawnSpeed);
}
```